# plotly subplots issue with specs, value error

Tags: plot, plotly, valueerror, plotly-python

I am trying to plot 3 subplots with secondary y axis with plotly subplots.
But no matter what I am trying, still getting this type of error.

ValueError:
The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (3 x 1).
Received value of type <class 'list'>: [[{'secondary_y': True}, {'secondary_y': True}, {'secondary_y': True}]]

Thank you for help

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data1 = {'number': [1,2,3,4], '1value': [20, 21, 19, 18],'2value': [30, 40, 65, 80],'3value': [400, 500, 600, 700]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)  

data2 = {'number': [1,2,3,4], '1value': [80, 120, 100, 200],'2value': [300, 60, 80, 150],'3value': [700, 800, 900, 1000]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'number': [1,2,3,4], '1value': [150, 200, 100, 170],'2value': [350, 40, 500, 200],'3value': [100, 200, 300, 400]}  
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)


fig = make_subplots (rows=3,cols=1,vertical_spacing=0.2,
                         specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}]])

    
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["number"], y = round(df1['1value'],1), mode = 'lines'), row=1, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["number"], y = round(df1['2value'],1), mode = 'lines'),row=1, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["number"], y = round(df1['3value'],1), mode = 'lines'),row=1, col=1,secondary_y=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["number"], y = df2['1value'], mode = 'lines'), row=2, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["number"], y = df2['2value'], mode = 'lines'), row=2, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["number"], y = df2['3value'], mode = 'lines'), row=2, col=1,secondary_y=False)
    
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d3["number"], y = df3['1value'], mode = 'lines'), row=3, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d3["number"], y = df3['2value'], mode = 'lines'), row=3, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=d3["number"], y = df3['3value'], mode = 'lines'), row=3, col=1,secondary_y=False)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly as per the error message.  Need a 2D 3x1 array of specs.  You defined a 1D array of length 3.

```
fig = make_subplots (rows=3,cols=1,vertical_spacing=0.2,
                         specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": True}]])
```

#### full code

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data1 = {'number': [1,2,3,4], '1value': [20, 21, 19, 18],'2value': [30, 40, 65, 80],'3value': [400, 500, 600, 700]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)  

data2 = {'number': [1,2,3,4], '1value': [80, 120, 100, 200],'2value': [300, 60, 80, 150],'3value': [700, 800, 900, 1000]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'number': [1,2,3,4], '1value': [150, 200, 100, 170],'2value': [350, 40, 500, 200],'3value': [100, 200, 300, 400]}  
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)


fig = make_subplots (rows=3,cols=1,vertical_spacing=0.2,
                         specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": True}]])

    
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["number"], y = round(df1['1value'],1), mode = 'lines'), row=1, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["number"], y = round(df1['2value'],1), mode = 'lines'),row=1, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["number"], y = round(df1['3value'],1), mode = 'lines'),row=1, col=1,secondary_y=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["number"], y = df2['1value'], mode = 'lines'), row=2, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["number"], y = df2['2value'], mode = 'lines'), row=2, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["number"], y = df2['3value'], mode = 'lines'), row=2, col=1,secondary_y=False)
    
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df3["number"], y = df3['1value'], mode = 'lines'), row=3, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df3["number"], y = df3['2value'], mode = 'lines'), row=3, col=1,secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df3["number"], y = df3['3value'], mode = 'lines'), row=3, col=1,secondary_y=False)
```